# Setting word document reference knitr via code

Tags: r, knitr

I am looking to build in a function into my R package that will allow users to put at the top of their rmarkdown a `use_style()` function call that when rendering to docx will format the word document to a specified template in the package inst folder.

I understand how to do this in the yaml header as per [here](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_docx.html) but cannot work out how to this in r code.

I'm looking to do something in the setup chunk as follows:

```
rmarkdown::word_document(reference_docx = "inst/styles/template.docx")
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Are there knitr options that allows this?

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to create a function linked to a file in inst that could be called in yams header. e.g.

output: pkgname:: rmarkdown_template

```
rmarkdown_template <- function(template) {

  # get the locations of resource files located within the package
  file <- system.file(paste0("styles/",template,".docx"), package = "dfeR")

  # call the base html_document function
  rmarkdown::word_document(reference_docx = file)
}
```